# Ext JS 4 file upload sending full path instead of file contents

Tags: extjs, file-upload

My dear colleagues,

I have the following scenario

- Some App uploads files to a File Storage through web service calls
- An Ext JS app is connected with Some App through a restful api

If I call the restful file upload controller with curl all is fine: the file is successfully uploaded.

The template for the command used:

```
curl -F "userid=1" -F "filecomment=This is a file" -F "file=@/home/user1/Desktop/test.txt;type=text/plain" localhost/uploader.php
```

If I post the Ext JS form to the restful controller, a file does get uploaded, but the contents of the file is the full path of the original file instead of it's contents, e.g.: /home/user1/Desktop/test.txt.

When examining the headers sent in the browsers network tab, Ext JS sends the data using a multipart content type. Client out-bound request headers from the controller towards the file storage endpoint are correct in both cases, however, when using curl, the file contents are posted, while Ext JS posts the filename itself.

Uploading through a non-ext js, plain old html form is also working fine! Thus the conclusion is, that Ext JS is the culprit.

Any suggestions on how to further debug this issue?

Comment: add `-X POST` and if its not enough add `-d @/home/user1/Desktop/test.txt` too

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate? I tried changing -F to -d and adding it as an additional parameter, but none of them work, curl gives a warning that I can select only one request.How does this supposed to help?

Comment: I thought the @ doesn't resolve the file content when you quote the parameter. But it seems that it does and it conflicts with the `-d` argument. I wrote an alternative solution as an answer (see below).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that Ext file upload components have an "submitValue" property which is true by default. This caused the path to be sent with the same key, thus overriding the file contents.